# nfs-common installation fails

Tags: debian, nfs

on newly installed Debian Wheezy machine, installation of `nfs-common` fails:

```
apt-get install nfs-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  open-iscsi watchdog
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nfs-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/288 kB of archives.
After this operation, 718 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nfs-common.
(Reading database ... 14755 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nfs-common (from .../nfs-common_1%3a1.2.6-4_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up nfs-common (1:1.2.6-4) ...

Creating config file /etc/idmapd.conf with new version

Creating config file /etc/default/nfs-common with new version
[FAIL] Starting NFS common utilities: statd failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript nfs-common, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing nfs-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`/var/log/syslog` has following erros:

```
2013-09-26 14:33:26  rpc.statd:  Failed to read /var/lib/nfs/state: Success
2013-09-26 14:33:26  rpc.statd:  Initializing NSM state
2013-09-26 14:33:26  rpc.statd:  Failed to access local netconfig database: Netconfig database not found
2013-09-26 14:33:26  rpc.statd:  failed to create RPC listeners, exiting
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you compile your kernel yourself? Try this...

http://sirlagz.net/2011/07/19/nfs-not-working/

Comment: It is better to provide the steps here, and use the link as a reference for further details. That way your answer does not loose all of it value when the link becomes invalid.